# Looking for a IDE plus SDK of JavaScript

Tags: javascript, sdk, ide, web-inspector

I am interested to know the best way to develop en JS. If I could get a list of tools for developing and debugging in JS. I am not sure if there. Currently, I am using:

Sumariing :)

1. Notepad++
2. JLint N++ pluggin
3. Chrome web inspector
4. WebStrom
5. Sublime Text 2
6. NetBeans 7.3
7. Dreamweaver

Comment: Add FireBug for FF, and you've got my dev environment. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Development Tools are always going to be subjective, but my current setup is:

1. [Visual Studio 2010](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express) - The express edition is free and still supports javascript intellisense.
2. [WebStorm by JetBrains](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/) - There's a paid version thats amazing.
3. [Firebug](http://www.getfirebug.com) Incredibly useful for debugging
4. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com) Web Proxy - Incredibly useful for debugging

You might also want to check out this list from Scott Hanselman: [Ultimate Developer and Power Users Tool List for Windows](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ScottHanselmans2011UltimateDeveloperAndPowerUsersToolListForWindows.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try NetBeans 7.3

- Project Easel: HTML5 Application Development
- HTML5 Application project with JavaScript testing support
- JavaScript Editor significantly improved
- Page inspector and visual CSS style editor
- JavaScript Debugger
- Embedded WebKit browser; deep integration with Chrome

http://netbeans.org/community/releases/73/

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what other languages you are using, your IDE may have JavaScript support.

I am using JetBrains PHPStorm to write PHP and the JavaScript support is excellent as it pre-compiles to check your code and give you intillisense.

This is a feature in many IDEs and it can really improve productivity as you will catch errors much earlier in your workflow.

Answer (score 0):

I use `Vim` + `jslint plugin` + `javascript syntax`, I also installed `ctags` which is very useful to switch between different functions.

`snippets` is also a very useful vim plugin.

Answer (score 0):

I find Webstorm to be the best but if you want free and open source try Eclipse. Also, firebug seems to work better than chrome debugger since you can install add-ons on firebug such as firecookie and many more.

Dreamweaver is also pretty good